# DB2 SQL Count across one to many relationship

Tags: sql, count, db2, ibm-midrange

I have two tables in a one to many relationship within an IBM DB2 database. I can't think of a way to describe what I'm doing in words easily so I'm linking an SQLFiddle.

Here is a working SQLFiddle on what I'm doing;
[Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71963/1)

The SQLFiddle works exactly like I need it to. My problem is, I am using an IBM DB2 database and the COUNT function does not seem to work. Does anyone have a way to return what the SQLFiddle does in a IBM DB2 compatible way?

Here is the error I get from i Navigator; [Click Here](http://prntscr.com/923wm2)

Comment: `COUNT()` works fine in IBM's databases.  Why do you think it is not working?

Comment: try what gordon said.. your group by should contain the fields in your Select that are not aggregates.. your query wouldnt work in Sql Server either.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e55c0/1

Comment: No, the function acts different from MySQL. Here is a link https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_count.dita

Comment: a lot of things work different in MySQL

Comment: error states the column `QT2VNB` doesnt exist in table `HPMODS.P0455`.. that's pretty straight forward error message

Comment: @JamieD77 The column does exist in the table HPMODS.P0455. Here is proof - http://prntscr.com/9240fi

Comment: Two things, did you really intend to do a `LEFT INNER JOIN`?  Also, the error message seems strange.  It appears you've qualified  `QT2CVNB`, yet the error message indicates it's an unqualified reference causing the problem.  Given the use of `LEFT INNER JOIN`...`COUNT(*)` should give the same results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating by the wrong column.  I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT Table1.quote, COUNT(Table2.quote) as TotalItem
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 
     ON Table1.quote = Table2.quote
GROUP BY Table1.quote
---------^
```

You need to aggregate by `Table1.quote` because `Table2.quote` might be `NULL`, because of the `LEFT JOIN`.

EDIT:

Your particular problem seems to be your having two tables with the same names.  Just use column aliases:

```
SELECT t1.quote, COUNT(t2.quote) as TotalItem
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.quote = t2.quote
GROUP BY t1.quote;
```

Comment: I get what your saying but it doesn't really matter. In my case, if table2 has a quote, then table1 will and vise versa.

Comment: I tried running the SQL this way. I still get an error when I run the SQL in i Navigator.

Comment: In your COUNT, shouldn't it be t2.quote? Table 2 is the many part of the relationship.

Comment: I tried to run your edit and it wont work in SQLFiddle.

Comment: @AJBirone You should include any errors since "it won't work" isn't very helpful. However, change `ON Table1.quote = Table2.quote` to be `ON T1.quote = T2.quote` and Gordon's statement should work.